# Pandas equivalent to SPSS mean.X

Tags: python, pandas

I come from a SPSS backround. In SPSS I can do:

> A minimal number of valid input values can be specified for statistical functions. This is done by suffixing the function with a period followed by the required number of valid values. For example compute mean_v = mean.2(v1 to v5).

This calculates the row mean of columns v_1 to v_5 - but only if 2 valid values are found.

Given the following dataframe and my current approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 5, 'b': None, 'c': None}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Try to emulate spss's mean.2

# Row Mean
df['row_mean'] = df[['a','b','c']].mean(axis=1) 

print df

# Condition .2 The second row should  be np.nan
df['row_mean_conditional'] = df[['a','b','c']].mean(axis=1) if df[['a','b','c']].count(axis=1) >= 2 else np.nan

print df
```

My current approach fails with `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I am not sure if I simply have to fix this - or if my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC then you want to [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna) with `thresh=2` to enforce that there must be at least 2 non `NaN` values and then call [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html):

```
In [131]:
df.dropna(thresh=2).mean(axis=1)
​
Out[131]:
0    2
dtype: float64
```

Also your approach won't work as you're trying to generate a scalar boolean value from an array comparison. Even if logically it would run this:

```
df[['a','b','c']].mean(axis=1)
```

would give you the mean for the second row anyway, to operate row-wise you can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) and pass a `lambda`:

```
In [137]:
df.apply(lambda x: x.mean() if x.count() >= 2 else np.NaN, axis=1)

Out[137]:
0     2
1   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks - super explanation!